# Not able to get proper response while calling POST method with parameter

Tags: java

Trying to calling post method using main method but getting 400 Bad request. I am using below code

```
private static String POST_URL = "http://localhost:8080/RestApi/api/v1/getDetails";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        sendPost();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred while calling service and exception is " + e);
    }
}

private static void sendPost() throws Exception {
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(POST_URL);
    post.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");

    // add request parameter, form parameters
    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "1004906799"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("identifer", "Customer"));

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault(); CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post)) {

        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
    }

}
```

> ```
> > Response : HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Connection: keep-alive,
> > X-Powered-By: Undertow/1, Server: WildFly/8, Content-Length: 0, Date:
> > Mon, 14 Oct 2019 09:44:34 GMT]
> ```

Comment: can you please paste stacktrace logs of 400 error?

Comment: can you post the rest endpoint which you are trying to hit. how is it configured?

Comment: The code is not consistent. According to `post.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")` you seem to want to post JSON, but you actually post a form containing 2 fields `id` and `identifier`. So is your service configured to accept a form or json ?

Comment: @Benoit Yes.. Service is accepting json

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting the encoding. Replace `post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));` line with

`post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters, "UTF-8"));`

Haven't run it but should work.

Comment: then possible issue is with your endpoint. Can you try running the endpoint in postman before making http call from java?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you post a form content rather than a JSON payload:

Replace those lines:

```
List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "1004906799"));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("identifer", "Customer"));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
```

with something like this:

```
String payload = "{\n" +
        "  \"id\": \"1004906799\",\n" +
        "  \"identifier\": \"Customer\"\n" +
        "}";
post.setEntity(payload);
```

See the section **4. POST with JSON** in [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-post-http-request).